# How can I pause a web page?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to inspect a web page which has a lot of DOM animation on it. Is there a Chrome plugin or any way to pause the webpage?

For example a Chrome button to pause the Javascript would do the trick.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, just run `debugger;` in the console.

It will immediately break the execution at this very statement.

Comment: Does `debugger` break the established tcp connections to the server of the webpage? @zerkms

Comment: Also, `debugger` does not allow me to interact with the webpage, I can not click links to open in new tab for example. Any way around that?

Comment: @Shayan don't put `debugger` and everything would be clickable and interactable

Comment: Yes but the page I'm working on has a script that refreshes on an interval, if I click on the resume button, the links that I want to click would be lost.

Comment: @Shayan please ask a separated question then.

Comment: _You can use in chrome shortcuts_:
F8 or Ctrl+\ (Windows)
F8 or Cmd+\ (Mac)

Answer (score 2):

Save this as a javascript bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(() => { setTimeout(() => { debugger; }, 1000); })()
```

Just copy it and paste it into bookmark bar.
Open dev tools, click on this bookmark. After 3 seconds it will pause the site.

Comment: Works like magic!

Comment: Excellent suggestion!!